# How to get the time at which the current user logged in in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm using [Laravel Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication). How can I get the time at which the current user logged in? I want to calculate the number of seconds that have passed since the current user logged in. If there is a way to achieve it without using [Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/events), it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished by overriding one of the methods from the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait inside the `Auth/LoginController`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * The user has been authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        $user->authenticated_at = Carbon::now();

        $user->save();

        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
}
```

And then recognize the date field on the user model:

```
...
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $dates = ['authenticated_at'];
...
```

And of course add this to the/a migration file for the users table:
`$table->timestamp('authenticated_at')->nullable();`

And a possible snippet you can use to get the 'uptime' via `$user->uptime`: (add to User model)

```
public function getUptimeAttribute(): int
{
    return Carbon::now()->diffInSeconds($this->getAttribute('authenticated_at'));
}
```